# Escape a # in rewrite rule in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm getting a `%23` in url when redirecting instead of the `#`. I tried escaping the hash with a `\`, but that didn't resolve. What am I missing?

Here's what I currently have:

```
# Redirect sub domain to external
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.come/path/with-a-hash/#/end-of-path/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [NE](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) to the list of flags passed to `RewriteRule` to say No Escaping.

> By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be
> converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents
> that from happening.
>
> ```
> RewriteRule "^/anchor/(.+)" "/bigpage.html#$1" [NE,R]
> ```
>
> The above example will redirect /anchor/xyz to /bigpage.html#xyz.
> Omitting the [NE] will result in the # being converted to its hexcode
> equivalent, %23, which will then result in a 404 Not Found error
> condition.